# Как сверстать кнопку как на картинке

Tags: html, css

[image: Кнопка с годами]

Не понятно как сверстать правую часть кнопки.

Answer (score 4):

Так

```html
<button style="
    float: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 4px;
">
Предыдущий
<div style="float: right;font-size: 13px;">
<div style="
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
">2016</div>
<div>2017</div>
</div>
</button>
```

ссылка для просмотра http://jsfiddle.net/46zLqupe/

Comment: Спасибо большое, данное решение очень помогло!

Answer (score 1):

[песочница](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/KxOZpZ) - обновлённая версия

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 190px;
  height: 60px;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  justify-content: center;
  background: linear-gradient(#fdfdfd, #ddd);
  margin: 20px;
}

.flex:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(#ddd, #fdfdfd);
}

.eyar {
  padding: 6px;
}

.eyar p{
 font-size:16px;
 line-height:16px;
 font-weight:550;
}

.eyar p:nth-of-type(1) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex" tabindex="-1">
  <p>Следующий</p>
  <div class="eyar">
    <p>2017</p>
    <p>2018</p>
  </div>
</div>
```